# Moving files without duplicating them to an S3FS-mounted storage bucket

Tags: mv, s3fs

Does the `mv` command (temporary) duplicate the moved files when the target is an S3FS mount?

I have a VM that is reaching total space consumption. So, I'd like to move some files to a storage bucket (**mounted using S3FS**) to free up some space.

Since I'm currently using 88.7% of 28.90GB, which is approximately 25.70GB and the directory I plan to move is 8.2GB, I'm afraid to use 100% and get stuck.

```shell
mv /path/sourcefolder/* /path/destinationfolder/
```

Comment: Do you have the option of just moving a few files manually first, so you have some breathing room, and only then move `*`?

Comment: If S3FS is just configured to save temporary files somewhere else (there might not be a "somewhere else" on this VM) I guess it doesn't matter what it does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

s3fs uses local temporary storage to write objects to S3.  `-o max_dirty_data` controls this amount and is set to 5 GB by default.  When copying a larger file, e.g., 10 GB, s3fs will write the first 5 GB locally then write to S3.  Afterwards it will write the second 5 GB to both then use a server-side copy to assemble the final object.  Thus if you are worried about using too much local storage you should decrease this value.  But doing so will trigger additional server-side copies, possibly slowing the overall write operation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Forgot to mention I'm talking about many "small" (up to 20/30 MB) files.

Comment: By default s3fs only uses local temporary space when writing files and you will only observe this with large ones.  If you enable `-o use_cache` it also stores data for future reads of files and should remove these when the file is closed.  You can control the latter indirectly via `-o ensure_diskfree`.

Answer (score -1):

`mv` *does not* duplicate the files. `cp` does.